# How to use the WS proxy configuration pattern in Mule

Tags: mule

I want to use WS Proxy Configuration pattern provided by Mule, I have pasted the config. file below

```
<pattern:web-service-proxy name="my-ws-proxy">
    <http:inbound-endpoint address="url1" />
    <http:outbound-endpoint address="url2" />
</pattern:web-service-proxy>
```

I have included the namespaces and schema required for using Mule's configuration patterns.

When I test it using SOAPUI I get Permission denied(Connect). I'm able to view the wsdl at url1?wsdl.

The console output is documented below.
INFO  2014-12-10 22:42:57,334 [[poc_proxy].connector.http.mule.default.receiver.03] org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager: Initialising: 'connector.http.mule.default.requester.1139151281'. Object is: HttpClientMessageRequester
INFO  2014-12-10 22:42:57,335 [[poc_proxy].connector.http.mule.default.receiver.03] org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager: Starting: 'connector.http.mule.default.requester.1139151281'. Object is: HttpClientMessageRequester
WARN  2014-12-10 22:42:57,915 [[poc_proxy].connector.http.mule.default.receiver.03] org.mule.expression.DefaultExpressionManager: Expression string is not an expression.  Use isExpression(String) to validate first

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure if the xml snippet you are passing is correct or not, I wonder if you are using expression in the url1 and url2?

Anyhow, those pattern constructions are being deprecated as per [MULE-7755](https://www.mulesoft.org/jira/browse/MULE-7755), personally I won't use them today in a new development.